# Selected output format is not supported with this function? Wikimapia API

Tags: kml, wikimapia

I have been trying with limited luck to instigate the &format=kml with the place.getbyarea function. I have been trying to isolate any additional paramater that might be conflicting with the exporting process. This has produced the same error every time.

```
http://api.wikimapia.org/?key=PUT_YOUR_KEY&function=place.getbyarea&coordsby=latlon&lon_min=35.37735&lat_min=33.055148&lon_max=36.333847&lat_max=34.694027&format=&pack=&language=en&page=1&count=50
```

Is there an issue with any of this input?